# How does being a pokemon gym leader work?

Tags: pokemon

Throughout the Pokemon world, there are these Pokemon gym leaders who serve as the gatekeepers for their regional Pokemon League region's championship. But how does being a gym leader work?

- How does one become a Pokemon gym leader?
- Is being a gym leader a full-time job?
- If it is full-time, how are they paid?
- What duties other than battling challengers do gym leaders have?
- Where does the money for building and maintaining the pokemon gyms come from?

Comment: Please clarify - do you mean within the games, the cartoons (and which cartoon?), or one of the various manga series?  Canon is different for each answer, and sometimes isn't fully explained (I don't beleive there is any explanation for these multiple different aspects of gym leadership in game canon)

Comment: @Zibbobz I don't really care which canon is used. If its different between sources, it would be interesting to see what the differences are.

Comment: Their duties are to find the very best, like no one ever was.

Comment: Most of your questions are answered here; http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gym_Leader

Comment: I suspect there are at least three separate questions in here (how do you become a leader; what do leaders do; how are the gyms maintained and funded). This site prefers multiple narrow questions to one broad one, so you may want to split this question up so it won't be closed as too broad.

Comment: I don't think that being a Gym Leader is a job assigned by government in Pokemon world. It's like forming a street gang. A pokemon trainer who thinks is best collects his friends and creates a gang. He might challenge other eligible people from the city to prove the best. Once confirmed as best, he declares himself as Gym Leader. Also he gets a place for himself to call Gym.

Now unlike real street gangs, a city can't allow outsider to become their Gym(gang) Leader. So in order to award outsider's superiority, they give them Badge. (This whole thing is assumptions based on my observations)

Comment: @Valorum You should post relevant details of that link in an answer.

Comment: @User867 - The question is closed (as too broad).

Comment: @Valorum Ah, so it is. I'm surprised I missed that.